# Flask and subprocess Popen - Send same data to multiple users

Tags: python, flask

The code below is almost what I need. But when second user connect, new subprocess.Popen created, i need run only one subprocess.Popen and send same data to multiple users.

Example: The first user connect, start subprocess.Popen, he begins to receive the result starting from the number 0, when second user connect 30 seconds after, he begins to receive result starting from de number 30.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from functools import partial
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

from flask import Flask, Response  # $ pip install flask

file = 'test.file'
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/' + file)
def stream():
    process = Popen([ "bash", "-c", "for ((i=0;i<100;i=i+1)); do echo $i; sleep 1; done" ], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=-1)
    read_chunk = partial(os.read, process.stdout.fileno(), 1024)
    return Response(iter(read_chunk, b''), mimetype='audio/mp3')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',threaded=True)
```

Comment: you can use a process like this to implement lazily loaded shared resources: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/extensiondev/#the-extension-code

Comment: I can not understand, would it be to use a database?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I am not sure if this will work. I do not use the `subprocess` module very much, so I am not sure if this is an appropriate use case. The question in general reminds me of flask extensions.

I was trying to suggest you use a similar pattern to flask extensions...

1. check if resource exists
2. if it does not, create it
3. return it

Store it on a Flask global, which is the API recommendation for extension development.

**edit:** realized your route was by file name so changed keys to reflect that

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from functools import partial
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from flask import Flask, Response, _app_ctx_stack as stack

file = 'test.file'
app = Flask(__name__)

def get_chunk(file):
    ctx = stack.top
    key = "read_chunk_%s" % file
    if ctx is not None:
        if not hasattr(ctx, key):
            process = Popen(["bash", "-c", "for ((i=0;i<100;i=i+1)); do echo $i; sleep 1; done"], 
                            stdout=PIPE, bufsize=-1)
            setattr(ctx, key, partial(os.read, process.stdout.fileno(), 1024))
        return getattr(ctx, key)


@app.route('/' + file)
def stream():
    read_chunk = get_chunk(file)
    return Response(iter(read_chunk, b''), mimetype='audio/mp3')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',threaded=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it did not work as expected, its condition "if not hasattr(ctx, key)" is always returning true and Popen is always started. If I'm understanding your point, I do not think it will work. I think I tried something similar https://paste.ubuntu.com/25187857/ , apparently when it creates the chunk it also erases the buffer, when the other user tries to get the data is not there anymore. A user will be for example with numbers 0,1,4 and the other with 2,3,5. In other words, it is not the same data!

Comment: Yea to be honest after I wrote this out I started to get a sense that you'd be better served by changing the approach. This would have been clunky at best. I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do (stream mp3s perhaps?). these are python functions i don't normally use and i've never seen in flask to be honest...

Comment: Mpegts streaming with ffmpeg, but checking several http parameter and ffmpeg result

Comment: Maybe an option is to target to hls as shown here https://github.com/ossrs/srs/wiki/v1_EN_DeliveryHLS#srs-how-to-support-hls , but I do not understand that language